# How to Preload Tabs/Set Multiple Websites as Default in Firefox, IE, etc

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer

Any website can set as the homepage of Firefox which loads spontaneously. Is this for multiple tabs? Then BBC Health, CNN, Yahoo Health, msn.com would all extemporarily materialise (in four separate tabs); I then wouldn't have to open each website manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With most browsers, it's quite simple to set up multiple homepages.

**Firefox**

> `Tools > Options`

Then as per the screenshot below.

[image: Firefox Homepage]

**Internet Explorer**

> `Tools > Internet Options`

Then as per the screenshot below.

[image: IE Homepage]

[image: IE Homepage 2]

**Google Chrome**

Not installed on this system, but the process is almost identical to the Firefox method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your browser to reopen all tabs that were open when you closed it. It will be in your internet settings.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, there's [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20set%20the%20home%20page#w_set-more-than-one-website-as-your-home-page):

> This is the way to have one-click access to all of your favorite websites. For example, you can set the Firefox home button to open your email, favorite news site, and Facebook all at once.
>
> 1. Open a new window and load the first web site you want in your home page.
> 2. Click the new tab button and open the next web site. Repeat this step until you've opened all the desired sites in new tabs.
> 3. At the top of the Firefox window, click on the **Tools** menu and then select **Options**
> 4. Select the **General** panel.
> 5. Click **Use Current Pages**.

For Internet Explorer, there's [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/change-home-page#ie=ie-11)

> To add or change home pages
>
> 2. On the Start screen, tap or click Internet Explorer to open Internet Explorer.
> 3. Go to a page that you'd like to set as a home page.
> 4. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Settings. (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, and then click Settings.)
> 5. Tap or click Options, and under Home pages, tap or click Customize.
> 6. Tap or click Add current site, edit the URL if you'd like, and then tap or click Add to make the site one of your home pages.
>
> The next time you open a new browsing session, this site and any other sites you've set up as home pages will load automatically.

Comment: Your Internet Explorer method is only really useful for Windows 8 users. When you follow your link there is a little down arrow on the right, where you can select which version of IE you are using.

Comment: I didn't notice that, but in truth, this question is easy enough to be Googled over...

Comment: Absolutely, but chances are that people finding this question are not going to click your link before trying the method you've described.

Comment: @MichaelFrank: Thank you very much. +1. Please do not be affronted by my selection which I also wanted to benefit users of fewer reputation.